# Python - how to get rid of the boundry range overlap between lines

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have a file whose inside looks like this:

`1  33725   36725   ENHANCER0002
1   711760  714760  ENHANCER0003
1   724150  727150  ENHANCER0004
1   725455  728455  ENHANCER0005
1   871280  874410  ENHANCER0006
1   874180  877180  ENHANCER0007
1   900540  903540  ENHANCER0008
1   901475  904475  ENHANCER0009
1   910260  913260  ENHANCER00010
1   933355  936355  ENHANCER00011
1   947660  950660  ENHANCER00012
1   1013530 1016530 ENHANCER00013
.
.
.
1   2477030 2480030 ENHANCER00043
1   2478160 2481160 ENHANCER00044
1   2478845 2481845 ENHANCER00045`

The middle two columns are my lower and upper boundaries. just as in line3-4 or line5-6, the boundaries overlap. I have to reshape it in a way, if boundaries overlap, it only prints the lowest lower boundary and highest upper boundary. I am working with Python for such solution and here is my code:

```
def write_line(chr_no,tmp_l,tmp_h,cnt,filename):
    filename.write(str(chr_no)+"\t"+str(tmp_l)+"\t"+str(tmp_h)+"\t"+"ENHANCER000"+str(cnt)+"\n")


inf = open("/home/firat/Desktop/Onder_Lab/Kenan/enhancers_bj.bed","r")
outf = open("/home/firat/Desktop/deneme_v3.bed","w")

cnt = 0
tmp_l=0
tmp_h=0

tmp_list = []

for line in inf:
    cnt += 1
    line = line.split(' ')
    current_low = line[1]
    current_high = line[2]
    previous_low = tmp_l
    previous_high = tmp_h
    if (int(current_low) <= int(previous_high)):
        tmp_list.append(int(current_low))
        tmp_list.append(int(current_high))
        tmp_list.append(int(previous_low))
        tmp_list.append(int(previous_high))
        write_line(line[0],min(tmp_list),max(tmp_list),cnt,outf)
        tmp_l = min(tmp_list)
        tmp_h = max(tmp_list)
        tmp_list = []
    else:
        write_line(line[0], previous_low, previous_high, cnt, outf)
        tmp_l= current_low
        tmp_h= current_high
```

Although my solution looks effective, the output is as this:

`1  27460   30460   ENHANCER0002
1   33725   36725   ENHANCER0003
1   711760  714760  ENHANCER0004
1   724150  728455  ENHANCER0005
1   724150  728455  ENHANCER0006
1   871280  877180  ENHANCER0007
1   871280  877180  ENHANCER0008
1   900540  904475  ENHANCER0009
1   900540  904475  ENHANCER00010
1   910260  913260  ENHANCER00011
1   933355  936355  ENHANCER00012
1   947660  950660  ENHANCER00013
1   1013530 1016530 ENHANCER00014
.
.
.
1   2477030 2481160 ENHANCER00044
1   2477030 2481845 ENHANCER00045
1   2477030 2481845 ENHANCER00046`

As noticed, there is duplication in printing when there is an overlap of boundaries. Also there are cases where 3 lines overlap just as in the very bottom. The expected output should be like:

`1  27460   30460   ENHANCER0002
1   33725   36725   ENHANCER0003
1   711760  714760  ENHANCER0004
1   724150  728455  ENHANCER0005
1   871280  877180  ENHANCER0006
1   900540  904475  ENHANCER0007
1   910260  913260  ENHANCER0008
.
.
.
1   2477030 2481845 ENHANCER00046`

What is wrong with my code and how can I improve it to work even if there is a more-than-2-lines overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems overly complicated for a simple task. You do not need to use four variables - tmp_l, tmp_h, previous_low and previous_high. You also do not need to maintain the current list of overlapping intervals. All you need to do is to maintain the low and high of the overlapping intervals.

The problem with your code, however, is that you call `write_line` every iteration. What you would instead want to do is call `write_line` only when the current low is more than the previous high, which would mean the previous set of overlapping intervals has ended, and also, at the end of the loop.

The following code would work:

```
for line in inf.splitlines():
    cnt += 1
    line = line.split(' ')
    current_low = int(line[1])
    current_high = int(line[2])
    if current_low <= previous_high:
        previous_high = current_high
    else:
        if previous_high > 0:
            write_line(line[0], previous_low, previous_high, cnt, outf)
        previous_low = current_low
        previous_high = current_high

if previous_high > 0:
    write_line(line[0], previous_low, previous_high, cnt, outf)
```

The check `if previous_high > 0` is needed to not output the default values for previous_low and previous_high - 0, 0. The extra write_line at the end of the for loop is needed to output the final set of overlapping intervals.

This code would work when there are more than 2 overlapping intervals, too.